# Advice on using MVC Spring framework with client side view

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I wanted some tips regarding the following problem, from the Java experts in this forum:

- I am currently working on a web application with lot of SQL transactions based on MVC architecture. Is is possible to have the view completely developed and hosted at the client side, with the controller and model at the server?
- The idea is to represent data in a way desired by end users. So, the View is developed (adhering to some defined standards) by the end users itself, where the controller and model remains the same.

I think it is possible with the MVC Spring framework, but don't know how exactly.

Thanks.
Shaun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is is possible to have the view completely developed and hosted at the client side, with the controller and model at the server?

What do you mean by this? Well, you may build HTML on client with Java Script by sending ajax requests for data to controller, but it's not the way Spring MVC designed for. For that you probably will need something like [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html)

Comment: What I mean is, me as a vendor for my web application want to give an option to my users to change (have their own) View (may be different logo, way to display data). So the idea is they see data the way they want, but I pass on data from my server.   [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/documentation/index.html) looks interesting. Can you comment on its complexity, as I have never used it before.

Comment: DWR is quite easy. It requires adding its servlet and some javascript code - and you are ready to go.